# Aliases with numerical names

Tags: zsh, alias, oh-my-zsh

I just installed Oh My ZSH on my Mac. Everything is working great, except I can't define aliases with numerical names.

If I execute

```
alias 5="cd ~/Projects/Projectname/"
5
```

I get the following error message:

```
cd:cd:10: no such entry in dir stack
```

Executing

```
cd ~/Projects/
```

works as expected.

This only seems happen with numerical aliases. Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: Well, I just tried and it worked for me. Maybe you have spaces in `projectname` ?

Comment: Also, try copy&paste what your alias should do into zsh prompt

Comment: wow, weird.  what does `alias 5` tell you?  i think this error should only happen if you do e.g. `cd +3` or `cd -4`, which you're clearly...  not

Comment: call `which 5` and post the results

Answer (score 2):

Probably, the set-up of "oh-my-zsh" is creating a function or alias with value/name `5` to `cd -5`.

Call `which 5` to verify that.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning a number as an alias of a command works perfectly fine. In fact, my oh-my-zsh uses the alias `5='cd +5'` by default.

I cannot reproduce your error, but I suspect your problem is that `cd` is either a function or an alias that's somehow incompatible with the alias you've defined. You can check with the command `which cd` if this is the case.

If I'm right, defining the alias as

```
alias 5='builtin cd ~/Projects/Projectname'
```

should solve your problem, since it will execute the built-in `cd` command.

Comment: if oh-my-zsh adds such an alias, then: 1. he has that alias set; 2. the error comes because his dirstack still lacks a 5th entry.

Comment: The error message searches for the *tenth* entry, and `alias 5="cd ~/Projects/Projectname/"` should overwrite any previously defined aliases of `5`.